# Do proposers of Stack Exchange sites get compensated in any way?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, business-model

I have an idea for a Stack Exchange site and was wondering if people who propose those sites get compensated in some way. Can they make money from advertising or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.  At least, no profit-generating scheme is built into the system for proposers.  Everything on SE sites is licensed [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/), except the source code.  Perhaps some enterprising person could find a third-party way to monetize the system, but that's outside the scope of Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: I got compensated when [the site I wanted with all my heart](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) got created (at least for a few more days)

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing to compensation anyone gets is reputation on Area51.

That being said, if the topic was one you have a sincere interest in, your reward is a shiny new site for your topic that you can ask / answer questions on.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that proposers of successful sites should get badges.  Maybe bronze if it hits commitment, silver if it hits beta, and gold if it gets out of beta.

Answer (score 0):

Indirectly you will get compensated. Not just for the above mentioned reasons, but also:

1. You can mention it on your CV (assuming it is work related - like [mine](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia) =:-) ) which may lead to a higher income and
2. You can a shiny, warm, glowing feeling of satisfaction inside at having made the world a better place*.

Note: *Your mileage may vary, subject to terms and conditions.*

Comment: Depending on your chosen profession, Gaming is totally work related.

Comment: @Grace Note - sounds fantastic...